# MYSQL - not enough results, change query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that selects 5 rows prior to the input datetime.

When the input datetime is close to the earliest date in my table I do not get 5 results, sometimes I get 4, 3, 2, 1 or none.

Is there a way to tell get it to select the remaining missing results (say the first query got 3 results so I need another 2) from random places in the table?

Comment: Please provide your code, it sounds like you're doing something wrong but we can't help you, if you don't provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the results older than $date_selected, latest first,

```
...
ORDER BY
  date_add<$date_selected, date_add, 0) DESC,
  RANDOM()
LIMIT 5
```

read as:
Select those before the selected date by their date, then those after the selected date.

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of:

```
select * from 
    (select 1 as resultOrder, *
    from    actualResults
    order by date desc
    limit 5
    union
    select  2 as resultOrder, *
    from    randomResults
    limit 5)
order by resultOrder
limit 5
```

Comment: sorry, I guess `LIMIT` for mySql, I did say "something along the lines of"